# Different definitions of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

In our lecture we have defined differentiability as follows:

$f:M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at point $a$ if $a$ is an interior point of $M$ and there exists a $n\times m$ matrix $A$ such that:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-A(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=0.
$$

In a book which I read and here on MSE I frequently came across the following alternative definition:

$f:M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at point $a$ if $a$ is an interior point of $M$, there exists a $n\times m$ matrix $A$, a function $\varphi(x)$ which is defined on a neighborhood of $0$ with the property $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{\varphi(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=0$ and a neighborhood $N_a$ of $a$ such that for all $x\in N_a$:
$$
f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a).
$$

So far I have mostly worked with the first definition. To me it seems to be easier to handle differentiability-problems with this definition.

However, I am wondering what the reasons might be to apply the second one? Maybe there are some good reasons from the vantage point of a more experienced mathematician? I would be happy to hear some opinions on that.

Comment: An applications of second definition is in the demostration of inverse function theorem and  implicit function theorem. Generally, you can use the first definition when you have a specific problem and you can use the second definition when you have a general problem about a differentiable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a big advantage: to prove things! Proving the properties of differentiable functions using the second definition is at least as simple and usually strictly simpler than using the first one.

Consider, for instance, the proof of the fact that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(a)$, then $g\circ f$ is differentiable at $a$. So, there is some matrix $A$ and some function $\varphi$ defined near $0$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\varphi(x-a)}{\|x-a\|}=0$ and that$$f(x)=f(a)+A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a);$$also, there is some matrix $B$ and some function $\mu$ defined near $0$ such that $\lim_{x\to f(a)}\frac{\mu(x-f(a))}{\|x-f(a)\|}=0$ and that$$g(x)=g(f(a))+B(x-f(a))+\mu(x-f(a)).$$So, let $\eta(x)=B\varphi(x)+\mu\bigl(Ax+\varphi(x)\bigr)$. Then\begin{align}g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)&=g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)+B(f(x)-f(a))+\mu(f(x)-f(a))\\&=g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)+B\bigl(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\bigr)+\mu\bigl(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\bigr)\\&=g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)+(BA)(x-a)+B\varphi(x-a)+\mu\bigl(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\bigr)\\&=g\bigl(f(a)\bigr)+(BA)(x-a)+\eta(x-a).\end{align}

Now, compare this with a proof using the first definition.

Comment: Do you have a short example at hand where I can see that it is much more complicated with the first one? Until now I have survived proving things with the first one and the proofs didn't seem too complicated this way.

Comment: I have added one such proof to my answer.

Comment: I find it very confusing that you also use $x$ as an argument when you talk about $g$. It would be clearer if you use $g(y)$ and then set $y=f(x)$. 

You wrote $\lim\limits_{x\to \bf\color{red}a}\frac{\mu(x-f(a)}{\Vert x-f(a)\Vert}$, I think it must be $\lim\limits_{x\to\bf{\color{green}{f(a)}}}\frac{\mu(x-f(a)}{\Vert x-f(a)\Vert}$, or better $\lim\limits_{\bf{\color{green}{y\to f(a)}}}\frac{\mu(y-f(a)}{\Vert y-f(a)\Vert}$. Moreover, how do we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\eta(x)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{B\varphi(x)+\mu\bigl(Ax+\varphi(x)\bigr)}{\Vert x- a\Vert}=0$?

Comment: Yes, it should have been the limit at $f(a)$; I've edited my answer. Now, note that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\varphi(x-a)}{\|x-a\|}=0$; since $B$ is linear, it follows from this that$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{B\varphi(x-a)}{\|x-a\|}=0.$$And, since $A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)=f(x)-f(a)$ and $\lim_{y\to f(a)}\frac{\mu(y-f(a)}{\|y-a\|}=0$, you also have$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\mu(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a))}{\|x-a\|}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|x-a\|}=0.$$And it follows from these equalties that$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{B\varphi(x-a)+\mu(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a))}{\|x-a\|}=0.$$

Comment: I can't follow you entirely, at first you say that $\lim\limits_{y\to{f(a)}}\frac{\mu(y-f(a))}{\Vert y-a\Vert}=0$ (which I think must be $\lim\limits_{y\to{f(a)}}\frac{\mu(y-f(a))}{\Vert y-f(a)\Vert}=0$). Then you conclude $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\mu\bigl(A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\bigr)}{\Vert x- a\Vert}= \lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\mu\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)}{\Vert x- a\Vert}$ which I understand. However, I don't see why $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\mu\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)}{\Vert x- a\Vert}=0$?

Comment: Yes, it should have been $\lim_{y\to f(a)}\frac{\mu(y-f(a))}{\|y-f(a)\|}$. And that final limit is $0$ because$$\lim_{x\to f(a)}\frac{\mu(x-f(a))}{\|x-f(a)\|}=0$$and because, since $f$ is continuous at $a$, when $x$ approaches $a$, then $f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$.

Comment: But you have to make sure that the denominator of $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{\mu\bigl(f(x)-f(a)\bigr)}{\Vert x- a\Vert}$ doesn't approach to $0$ faster than the nominator. This still could be the case despite $f$ being continuous and $\lim\limits_{x\to f(a)}\frac{\mu\bigl(x-f(a)\bigr)}{\Vert x- f(a)\Vert}=0$ .

Comment: No, that *cannot* be the case. Take $\varepsilon>0$; you want to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$\|x-a\|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|x-a\|}\right|<\varepsilon.$$You know that there is a $\delta_0>0$ such that$$\|y-f(a)\|<\delta_0\implies\left|\frac{\mu(y-f(a))}{\|x-f(a)\|}\right|<\varepsilon.$$Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\|x-a\|<\delta\implies\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\delta_0$ and therefore$$\|x-a\|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|x-a\|}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I still don't understand your last implication, which is actually the crucial step. I think we need more information about $\mu$. Only because $\Vert x -a\Vert <\delta$ and $\Vert f(x)-f(a)\Vert<\delta_0$ we don't know if $|\mu(f(x)-f(a))|$ is small enough to make the fraction $\Big|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\Vert x-a\Vert} \Big|<\epsilon$, we only know that $\Vert f(x)-f(a)\Vert<\delta_0$ makes $\Big|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\Vert f(x)-f(a)\Vert} \Big|<\epsilon$.

Comment: My I assume that you agree with my first two sentences?

Comment: Yes everything in your comment until the part *...and therefore...* is clear.

Comment: But then we have\begin{align}\|x-a\|<\delta&\implies\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\delta_0\\&\implies\left|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}\right|.\end{align}What can possibly fail here?

Comment: Nothing, this is correct. The point is that I don't see why the third implication you made is true: $$\Vert x -a\Vert <\delta\implies \Vert f(x)-f(a)\Vert<\delta_0\implies\Big|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\Vert f(x)-f(a)\Vert} \Big|<\epsilon\color{red}{\overset{?}{\implies}}\Big|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\Vert x-a\Vert} \Big|<\epsilon.$$

Comment: You're right: my argument is incomplete. Sorry about that. Note that$$\left|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|x-a\|}\right|=\left|\frac{\mu(f(x)-f(a))}{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}\right|.\frac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}.$$But$$\frac{\|f(x)-f(a)\|}{\|x-a\|}=\frac{\|A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$$and, since $A$ is linear and since $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\varphi(x-a)}{\|x-a\|}=0$, the function$$x\mapsto\frac{\|A(x-a)+\varphi(x-a)\|}{\|x-a\|}$$is bounded near $a$.